# Can't start isc-dhcp-server due to error " AgentInitCheck: agent comms failure"

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 - Model B, and I'm trying to create an adapter from Wi-Fi to Ethernet using the Pi. I'm currently using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Konamiman/110adcc485b372f1aff000b4180e2e10) as a guide for how to create it, but I keep running into an error when I start the DHCP server.

When I run `service isc-dhcp-server start`, I receive this message:

```sh
Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The log from `systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service` shows this:

```sh
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-30 11:24:41 EST; 8s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2444 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 30 11:24:39 raspberrypi dhcpd[2454]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Dec 30 11:24:39 raspberrypi dhcpd[2454]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Dec 30 11:24:39 raspberrypi dhcpd[2454]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Dec 30 11:24:39 raspberrypi dhcpd[2454]:
Dec 30 11:24:39 raspberrypi dhcpd[2454]: exiting.
Dec 30 11:24:41 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[2444]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
Dec 30 11:24:41 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[2444]:  failed!
Dec 30 11:24:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 30 11:24:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 30 11:24:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
```

In looking for a more verbose log, I ran `journalctl -xe`, which displays this:

```sh
-- The unit isc-dhcp-server.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 30 11:24:41 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit isc-dhcp-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit isc-dhcp-server.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 2101 and the job result is failed.
Dec 30 11:24:41 raspberrypi sudo[2418]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 30 11:24:45 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[492]: AgentInitCheck: agent comms failure
Dec 30 11:24:50 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[492]: AgentInitCheck: no response from agent
Dec 30 11:24:55 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[492]: AgentInitCheck: agent comms failure
Dec 30 11:25:00 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[492]: AgentInitCheck: no response from agent
Dec 30 11:25:05 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[492]: AgentInitCheck: agent comms failure
```

Frustratingly enough I'm not exactly sure what `agent comms failure` means and what I need to do to fix it. What's wrong with what I'm doing? For reference, I'll show my DHCP configuration files.

`/etc/dhcpd.conf`:

```sh
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.34.1/24
```

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```sh
authoritative;
subnet 192.168.34.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.34.10 192.168.34.250;
 option broadcast-address 192.168.34.255;
 option routers 192.168.34.1;
 default-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200;
 option domain-name "local-network";
 option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

`/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`:

```sh
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server (sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
DHCPDv4_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#DHCPDv6_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
DHCPDv4_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid
#DHCPDv6_PID=/var/run/dhcpd6.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#       Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#       Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACESv4="eth0"
INTERFACESv6=""
```

Comment: i would given `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start|tail -f /var/log/syslog` a shot due it logs into syslog